# Is there anyway I can secure my connection when I try to log in to my router remotely?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to configure my desktop to be accessed remotely. Here's what I've done so far:

- enabled wake on lan / remote wake up on all interfaces.
- I'm using logmein as my remote desktop application.
- setup DDNS so that I can log in to my router.

When I try to remotely log in to my router it says that it is not encrypted there anyone can see my log in information. What can I do to make this a more secure setup? Any other suggestions or different methods will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many consumer routers will allow you to choose to run the management web interface over HTTPS (For example on a Linksys WRT54G you can see this [example GUI](http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT54G/v8.2/8.2.05/Manage.htm)).  Enabling HTTPS would encrypt all transactions between your browser and the router, including passing the username/password.  You would however have to make sure that when you type in your DynDNS name you use `https://example.dyndns.com` emphasis on the http**s**

Comment: Ok, thanks. I enabled https and everything is still fine.